# Texto muito extenso no "Stack Exchange Button"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, stackexchange-button

Isto é mais um problema por mudança do tipo da fonte, o que tem afetado vários textos, vejam como esta (este problema não ocorre nos sites que estão em inglês devido ao tamanho do texto):

[image: bug da quebra de texto]

O problema é que agora estão usando o `<h3>`:

```
h3 {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

E o `font-variant: small-caps;`:

```
.topbar-dialog .header h3, .topbar-dialog .header h3 a {
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif !important;
    color: #6a737c;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    line-height: .8;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Eu pessoalmente acho desnecessário esta diferença de tamanho, os títulos estão dentro de divs com cores que contrastam, as fontes podem ter o mesmo tamanho, é apenas uma sugestão.

Comment: Poderia apontar pra mim? Não estou vendo o problema

Comment: @bigown tente abrir uma aba privativa, pode ser o cache

Comment: Não estou vendo nem na sua imagem colada na pergunta :)

Comment: @bigown olhe em seu console, deve ser um problema de rede, ou algum adblock mal configurado

Comment: @bigown procura no fundo por _"blog da empresa"_ que não teve espaço nessa linha cinzenta e caiu para baixo.

Comment: @Sergio agora vi, ele sobrepõe um pouco sim.

Comment: Sergio @bigown editado a imagem (gostaria muito que os comentários suportassem ao menos 3 usuários com `@`)

Comment: Acho que só "Mais Comunidades" já está bom, tem "stack exchange" no topo, meio e rodapé do site, sei lá se tem necessidade de repetir isso em todo canto.

Comment: @renan posso estar enganado, mas os do rodapé são apenas os mais populares e ali o foco deve ser SEO. Já o do botão é totalmente voltado ao usuário, principalmente os autenticados.

Comment: No meu está direito.

Answer (score 8):

Troquei as strings por versões mais curtas:

- "Mais comunidades do stack exchange" `->` "Mais comunidades Stack Exchange"
- "Encontre uma comunidade do Stack Exchange" `->` "Procure uma comunidade"

## Atualização

Diminuir as strings não deu jeito, avisei os designers e vamos ver...

Comment: Até os textos soam melhor, só uma nota, isso esta errado "Mais comundiades Stack Exchange" (comundiades).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Fui olhar, só errei aqui no post. No Transifex tá certo!

Comment: Engraçado, pra mim não sobrepunha nem com o texto mais longo. Deve depender de browser/OS/fontes.

Comment: @bfavaretto Aqui também não. Mas eu tenho um monitor gigante, então....

Comment: Problema parece ocorrer no Windows8 apenas, não pude testar outros, de inicio pensei ser um problema de alguma fonte que instalei, mas em outro computar limpo o problema ocorreu também. Vou analisar e depois lhe dou um retorno.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ainda ocorre, mesmo depois da mudança de strings?

Comment: @Gabe desculpe a demora, ocorre sim, é que estou tentando instalar outro sistema operação em uma maquina virtual pra testar se é um problema com as fontes no momento da renderização.

Comment: @Gabe obrigado, parece que resolveram, não achei qualquer menção no  meta.stackexchange sobre o problema, todavia esta corrigido.

Answer (score 1):

O problema ainda existia a alguns dias, todavia notei hoje que foi resolvido, não devido a mudança de texto, mas sim do CSS, antes era assim (como citei na pergunta):

```
.topbar-dialog .header h3, .topbar-dialog .header h3 a {
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif !important;
    color: #6a737c;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    line-height: .8;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Atualmente esta assim:

```
.topbar-dialog .header h3, .topbar-dialog .header h3 a {
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif !important;
    color: #6a737c;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: .8;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Trocaram `font-variant: small-caps;` por `font-size: 11px;` + `text-transform: uppercase;`, o que parece que resolveu.